# Friends highscore: merging two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, multidimensional-array

I'm developing a game on Facebook and want to show the users a friends highscore.
What's the most efficient way to do this?

I have two arrays:

The first one, `$all`, coming from my database, holds the fbid's and the score's of ALL users who played the game:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 12345
            [score] => 0
            [endgame] => 1404316845
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 112873
            [score] => 0
            [endgame] => 1404334512
        )
    ...
)
```

The second one, `$friends`, coming from Facebook, holds ALL the user's friends:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 12345
            [name] => Some Name
            [pic_square] => https://...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 43324324
            [name] => Another Name
            [pic_square] => https://...
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 4893424242
            [name] => Yet Another
            [pic_square] => https://...
        )
    ...
)
```

I think the prefered method here is to generate an new array, which contains only friends who played the game and have a score, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 12345
            [name] => Some Name
            [pic_square] => https://...
            [score] => 0
            [endgame] => 1404316845
        )
    ...
)
```

I've tried various things using `in_array`, but can't get it right... Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array for the scores that is indexed by `uid`.

```
$indexedScores = [];

foreach($all as $score) {
    $indexedScores[$score['uid']] = $score['score'];
}
```

Then loop through the friends array and set the score by looking up `$indexedScores`

```
foreach($friends as $key => &$friend) {
    if(isset($indexedScores[$friend['uid']])) {
        $friend['score'] = $indexedScores[$friend['uid']];
    }
    else {
        unset($friends[$key]); //doesn't have a score, so remove
    }
}

usort($friends, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['score'] > $b['score'];
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "Then loop through the friends array and set the score by looking up $indexedScores" and with the code that follows... I've tried your code but it didn't work. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: @binoculars try again, I was referencing `$scores` instead of `$indexedScores` - `$indexedScores` is an associative array where the keys are uids, so you can use `isset` to see if a given uid has a score or not

Comment: Nice one, work like a charm... Now all I need to do is rearrange the array so the scores are descending... I've read about `arsort()` but how does this work with multidimensional arrays?

Comment: any idea how I can add endgame to the new array (see update), and then sort the whole array on score first, and endgame second? (if two players have the same score, the one who got the score first (=endgame) should be ranked above the other one)